# Possible Twilight Zone or Outer Limits

Tags: story-identification, tv, powers

An engineer/scientist is revived from cryogenic sleep in the future of a farm community. He is operated on to remove a tumor and needs to repair a transmitter. The transmitter is repaired and a spaceship is destroyed. The ship contained generals that will continue war that all but destroyed civilization. The remaining humans are now capable of exploring the universe with their mind.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195284/man-awaken-from-suspended-animation-to-stop-an-asteroid-heading-towards-earth-w (which is newer but has a more complete question and answer)

Answer (score 13):

It's [*Quarantine,*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarantine_%28The_Twilight_Zone%29) episode 42, season 1 of the new twilight zone series that aired in 1986. It has all the features that the OP described - engineer revived from cryosleep, peaceful psionic future humans, ship full of old military types. You can view it on YouTube [here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QefiNX9W9Jk)

Comment: Well spotted. I was thinking this was TOL : The refuge. It's got a lot of the same themes.